# Autosys Load Balancer and Machine Stickiness

Tags: autosys

I have a configuration where an autosys virtual machine points to several real machines. That means a job pointing to the virtual machine could execute of any of the real machines depending on the load on those machines. This is a desired feature for me.

Now, I have a job stream comprising 2 jobs. Job 1 creates a file and Job 2 reads the file. Each job uses its local storage. So if job 1 runs on real machine 1 and jobs 2 starts on real machine 2, it will not find the file. Is there a way to ensure one stream of jobs is always executed on one machine? I don't have a problem if load balancing schedules different streams on different machines.

If not possible, what are other ways people address such concerns? Using a shared storage like NAS?

This is what I referring to for documentation: https://docops.ca.com/ca-workload-automation-ae/11-4-2/en/scheduling/ae-scheduling/real-and-virtual-machines/how-load-balancing-works

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with placing the actual physical machine name in the "machine" parameter instead of the virtual load balancer machine name.

In virtual machine, as you illustrated, it might not be possible that the load balancer will run the second job on the same machine in which the job 1 is run.

So if you keep the physical machine name in the "machine" section, your problem will be solved.